# PackageKit: won't overwrite previous version?

Tags: macos, pkgbuild, pkg-file

My installer won't overwrite the previous version for some unknown reason. The old version installed on my computer is 0.916 and the new version is 0.92. Here's part of the installer log...

```
PackageKit: Skipping component "com.XXX.myPlugin" (0.92.0-0.92.0-*-*) because the version 0.916.0-0.916.0-*-* is already installed at /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/myPlugin.component.

PackageKit: Skipping component "com.XXX.myPlugin" (0.92.0-0.92.0-*-*) because the version 0.916.0-0.916.0-*-* is already installed at /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/myPlugin.vst.
```

There's also a line in there that says:

```
PackageKit: Session UUID file exists - will not overwrite /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/FB11F7E9-0C1D-4EB1-BC06-7D1C82E7CD4C.activeSandbox
```

Not sure what's going on here. I have no idea why it wouldn't overwrite 0.92 over 0.916.

Anyone come across this?

Comment: 916 is greater than 92, so PackageKit considers that a more recent version of the component is already installed, and therefore skips the install.